# convert list<map<string,object>> to object of a POJO class

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, pojo

I have a List of HashMap objects in which hashMap object contains property name as key and value of property as value list>. How to convert each of these HashMap object into an object of my POJO class.??

Comment: Consider using reflection and/or Apache commons-beanutils

Comment: See if [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldValues.html)  helps. briefly explained reflection example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can do it using [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/):

Pojo class:

```
public class MyPojo {
    private String text;
    private Integer number;

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public Integer getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(Integer number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

Populate instances of your pojo using reflection;

```
final List<Map<String, Object>> objects = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
objects.add(new HashMap<String, Object>());
objects.get(0).put("text", "This is my text value.");
objects.get(0).put("number", 10);
objects.add(new HashMap<String, Object>());
objects.get(1).put("text", "This is my second text value.");
objects.get(1).put("number", 20);

ArrayList<MyPojo> pojos = new ArrayList<MyPojo>();

for (Map<String, Object> objectMap : objects) {
    MyPojo pojo = new MyPojo();
    for (Entry<String, Object> property : objectMap.entrySet()) {
        Method setter = MyPojo.class.getMethod("set" + property.getKey().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()
                + property.getKey().substring(1), property.getValue().getClass());
        setter.invoke(pojo, property.getValue());
    }
    pojos.add(pojo);
}

for (MyPojo pojo : pojos) {
    System.out.println(pojo.getText() + " " + pojo.getNumber());
}
```

Output:

> This is my text value. 10
>
> This is my second text value. 20